# TypeError at /login login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'User'

Tags: python, django

i am getting error "TypeError at /login
login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'User'"

i am new to django.
trying to create a login page.

this is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate



def index(request):
    
    return render(request,'index.html',)

def login(request,User):
    if request.method=='POST':
        username= request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user=authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        if user is not None:
            user.login(request,user)
            

            return render(request,'welcome.html',)

        else:
            messages.info(request , 'invalid credentials')
            return render(request,'login.html')
    else:
        return render(request,'welcome.html')
```

this is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('login',views.login,name='login'),
    path('register',views.register,name="Login now")
    
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `login` view should not contain a `User` parameter, in fact for the given view, you do not need to import the `User` model at all. Furthermore in order to login, you should use the [**`login(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login). Since you already have a method named `login`, you should import it under a different name:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login

# no User parameter
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth_login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'welcome.html',)
        else:
            messages.info(request , 'invalid credentials')
            return render(request, 'login.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'welcome.html')
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.